# How to use k-fold cross validation in naive bayes classifier?

Tags: classification, cross-validation, text-mining, validation

I'm trying to classify text using naive bayes classifier, and also want to use k-fold cross validation to validate the result of classification. But I'm still confused how to use the k-fold cross validation. As i know that k-fold divide data to k subsets, then one of the k subsets is used as the test set and the other k-1 subsets are put together to form a training set. And i think as training set the data must have label to be trained. So to use k-fold cross validation the required data is the labeled data?, is it right?, and how about non labeled data?.

Comment: Do you have your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close to understanding k-fold cross-validation.  To answer your questions in turn.

**1. So to use k-fold cross validation the required data is the labeled data?**

Yes, you must have some 'known' result in order for your model to be trained on the data.  You are building a model, I assume, to predict some sort of outcome either regression or classification.  In order to do so, a model must be built on data to explain some known result.

**2. How about non labeled data?**

For k-fold cross-validation, you will have split your data into k groups (e.g. 10).  You then select one of those groups and use the model (built from your training data) to predict the 'labels' of this testing group.  Once you have your model built and cross-validated, then it can be used to predict data that don't currently have labels.  The cross-validation is a means to prevent overfitting.

As a last clarification, you aren't only using 1 of the 10 groups.  Let's say you had 100 samples.  You split it into groups 1-10, 11-20, ... 91-100.  You would first train on all the groups from 11-100 and predict the test group 1-10.  Then you would repeat the same analysis on 1-10 and 21-100 as the training and 11-20 as the testing group and so forth.  The results typically averaged at the end.

As a simple example say I have the following abbreviated data (binary classification):

```
Label    Variable
A        0.354
A        0.487
A        0.384
A        0.395
A        0.436
B        0.365
B        0.318
B        0.327
B        0.381
B        0.355
```

Let's say I want to do 10-fold cross-validation on this (nearly Leave-One-Out cross-validation in this case)

My first testing group will be:

```
A        0.354
A        0.487
```

My training set is the remaining data.  See how the labels are present in both groups?

```
A        0.384
A        0.395
A        0.436
B        0.365
B        0.318
B        0.327
B        0.381
B        0.355
```

**Please note that it is also best practice to randomize the grouping, this is purely for demonstration**

Then you fit your model to the training set, which is using the variable(s) to best explain the labels (class A or B).  The model that has been fit to this training set is then used to predict the testing dataset.  You remove the labels from the testing set and predict them using the trained model.  You then compare the **predicted labels** to the **actual labels**.  This is repeated for all 10-folds and the results averaged.

Once everything is completed and you have your wonderfully cross-validated model, you can use it to predict **unlabeled** data and have some sort measure of confidence in your results.

**Extended for Parameter Tuning**

Let's say you are tuning a partial least squares (PLS) model (it doesn't matter if you don't know what this is for demonstration purposes).  I would like determine how many components (the tuning parameter) I should have in the model.  I would like to test 2,3,4, and 5 components and see how many I should use to maximize my predictive accuracy without overfitting the model.  I would conduct the **entire cross-validation series for each component number**.  Each iteration of the CV would be averaged (the average predictive accuracy of the entire analysis).

Assuming classification accuracy is your metric let's say these are my results (completely made up here):

```
2 components: 70%
3 components: 82%
4 components: 78%
5 components: 74%
```

Clearly, I would then choose 3 components for my model which has now been cross-validated to avoid overfitting and maximizing predictive accuracy.  I can then use this optimized model to predict a new dataset where I don't know the labels.

Comment: example if i had 100 samples, then i split it into 10 groups, first i choose to predict label of 1-10 groups, so the 11-100 have to be trained, but to trained the 11-100 i need label, right?, so i stil need label?, so i cant use non labeled data?. i'm still confused.

Comment: @MuhammadHaryadiFutra, during this stage of building a model all of your data needs labels.  The labels are initially removed from the testing subset but compared to after predication and therefore still required. Since you are trying to predict something, you must have some 'known' values to compare (i.e. labels).  Once you have a properly built and validated model, then you can use the model to predict non-labeled data.

Comment: I think i need an example to clearly understand. do you have any example?, please help me.

Comment: as i knowed there are two section in naive bayes classifier, training and testing. Training section is to train the labeled data to make a model, then the testing section is to predict class/label of the new testing/non labeled data after the model was made. So i think k-fold only used on training section? and can't be used in testing section. is it right?

Comment: @MuhammadHaryadiFutra, see the simple example I have provided above.  Does this clarify things?

Comment: Ya i got it, so the function of cross validation actually to produce the best model which can be used to predict the label of the other data either labeled or not?, right?

Comment: Now i'm confused how to calculate the result of cross validation, for comparison with the previous models to know which model is the best.

Comment: @MuhammadHaryadiFutra, you would run cross validation several times.  Once for each tuning parameter(s) of interest.  The cross validation provides a means to avoid bias when comparing different models.  Cross validation doesn't give you the tuning parameters (i.e. best model) you must run CV for each one and then select the parameters with the best results.  Does this make sense?

Comment: How about i choose the model created by the last fold of cross validation?, is it good?

Comment: @MuhammadHaryadiFutra, ABSOLUTELY NOT!!!  That would defeat the entire purpose of cross-validation.  If you are using CV to choose your model parameters, you must run it for each level of the parameter (i.e. grid based optimization) and average the results to compare the different parameter levels without excessive bias.

Comment: i totally confused, i really need a complete example. sorry :(

Comment: @MuhammadHaryadiFutra, I have added a very simple example of parameter tuning.  Does this clarify things?

Comment: Thankyou so much, i got it. i think i can use precision and recall to get the best model, can i?

Comment: @MuhammadHaryadiFutra, yes, in theory you can use whatever metric you like to measure performance so long as you can support your decision.  Glad I could help you understand.  If you are satisfied, please accept the answer.

Comment: and now i'm confused how to get the TP,FP,FN,and TN value of confussion matrix. :(

Comment: @MuhammadHaryadiFutra, [here](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~dbd/cs831/notes/confusion_matrix/confusion_matrix.html) is a link for a basic binary classification matrix.  However, for the future, if you have another question not 'directly' connected (e.g. not CV) you should just create another question.